# Will file_get_contents fail gracefully?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I need [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to be fault tolerant, as in, if the `$url` fed to it returns a **404**, to tell me about it before it echos out a warning. Can this be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any function that uses the HTTP wrapper to access a remote file as if it were local will automatically generate a local variable named [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) in the local scope. You can access that variable to find information about what happened in a call to `fopen`, `file_get_contents` ... on a remote file.

You can suppress the warning using `@`: `@file_get_contents`.

If you don't care about what the error was, you can use `@file_get_contents` and compare the result to `false`:

```
$content = @file_get_contents(url);
if ($content === false) { /* failure */ } else { /* success */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do an additional (HEAD) request to find out first, for instance

```
$response = get_headers($url);
if($response[1] === 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Or you can tell `file_get_contents` to ignore any errors and force-fetch the result of the `$url` by modifying the stream context:

```
echo file_get_contents(
    'http://www.example.com/foo.html',
    FALSE,
    stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('ignore_errors' => TRUE)))
)
```