# Detect remote parse error in php file_get_contents

Tags: php, remote-access

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131607), but not exactly.

If I do `$string = @file_get_contents('http://www.somesite.com/script.php');` and there's a parse error in script.php, `$string` gets the value of the parse error, not bool false.  The error is not on the local site, but on the remote one.

I supposed I'll have to do string comparisons to check for that case, but is there a list of certain strings I should look for like `'<b>Parse error</b>:'` and `'<b>Warning</b>:'`? Is there a better way to check for an error on the remote script?

(I have control over both domains, in case that makes a difference in your suggestions.)

Here's the code I put on the remote server:

```
  if(!$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
    {
      echo('Can you get me?');
    }
  else
    {
      foreach ($imnotanarray as $fail) //intentionally cause an error
        {
          echo $fail;
        }
    }
```

Here's the code from the local server

```
$success=file_get_contents('http://www.tecbrat.com/fgc_responder.php');
$success_header=$http_response_header[0];

$failure=file_get_contents('http://www.tecbrat.com/fgc_responder.php?do=fail');
$failure_header=$http_response_header[0];

$failure2=@file_get_contents('http://www.tecbrat.com/fgc_responder.phxp');
$failure2_header=$http_response_header[0];

echo 'Success is '.$success.'and the header is '.$success_header."<br><br>\n\n";
echo 'Failure is '.$failure.'and the header is '.$failure_header."<br><br>\n\n";
echo 'Another Failure is ';
var_dump($failure2);
echo ' and the header is '.$failure2_header;
```

Comment: PHP errors usually go along with a 500 http status code. I'm not sure if you can catch that with file_get_contents, but you could reach that goal using [curl](http://www.php.net/curl)

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't parse errors throw HTTP 500?  Maybe you can check for that?

Comment: No, My test script said: `Failure is 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /home/tecbrat/public_html/fgc_responder.php on line 9
and the header is HTTP/1.1 200 OK
`

Comment: I added some code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with that output, searching for a parse error using substring matching is indeed your best bet.

If you feel that's inelegant - and you'd be absolutely right to feel this way - the Right Way to handle this is to add some error handling and represent a parse error in a more integrated fashion, so if your service usually returns an XML object or something it returns an XML object containing error data.

Comment: Do you know if all PHP errors always start with `'<b>'`? In this particular instance, the expected return is plain text, but I don't think it would EVER start with that string.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to verify that it's bolded, do you? You could always run the results through HTML Purifier so you're checking plaintext regardless.

Comment: I found that, at least on my server, errors are presented with `"<br />\n<b>ERROR_TYPE</b>"` at the very beginning so I'll check for `"<br />\n<b>"`.