# twitch file_get_contents php gives 404 instead of error json

Tags: php, json, twitch

I am trying to fetch user info with `file_get_contents()` with the use of twitch api. When I test the link in my browser with both existing and non existing, it works fine for both cases (returns user object in case user exists, and error object if user does not exist).

However, when I want to accomplish the same in `PHP` with `file_get_contents()`, it does work fine when the user exists, but when it does not, PHP throws `Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

My code looks like this:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.$username);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I am also getting an 404 code when I open it in my browser. Care to elaborate what you would expect? Getting the JSON from the response anyways? For what purpose? I agree that having an error as negative result is not the best way to check that case. However, maybe file_get_contents() is not the best approach then and you should look into using e.g. cURL.

Comment: What is the question ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to get an error json if user with the provided username does not exist instead of php generating error. I see this in browser when I try to test in browser's address bar: {"error":"Not Found","status":404,"message":null}

Comment: I'd rather not use cURL for something as trivial as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to parse the JSON no matter if there is a valid HTTP code (e.g. 200) or an invalid one (e.g. 404). The problem of PHP is here, that it fails if there is an invalid HTTP response code. You can however force PHP to accept this by using a flag in the method call. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4132660/3233827 for that.

Comment: This is what i was looking for.